# Phoenix Production Server

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, production-environment

New to Erlang, Elixir and Phoenix.

I've hello-world'ed with Phoenix on my Ubuntu instance by running `mix phoenix.server`.  It stays up for less than an hour before it goes down.  Clearly this isn't the fabled 99.999999% uptime that Erlang boasts, so I have to assume this is a dev server.

What is Phoenix doing when I run `mix phoenix.server`, and how do I get it to run in production?

Comment: What is the error it exits with?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this *on* a production server or asking about running the code in the *production* environment locally?

If you just want to run that command and use the *production* environment (which disables some extra debug logging and so-on) you can do a `MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server`

Long-term, if running on a server - I would recommend looking at releases via [distillery](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery) because then you are just pushing a binary to the server and not installing Elixir at all (and not running `mix phoenix.server`) - less moving parts to worry about.

I can't speak for your issue you are having - But as someone mentioned above, the first step is to look at your logs. It's just really hard to guess without more details.

Good luck!